# NOT NULL constraint failed: registratie_inkomen.pg_id

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

This are my models:

```
class PersoonGegevens(models.Model):
    # Voornaam en achternaam
    voornaam = models.CharField(max_length=265,)
    achternaam = models.CharField(max_length=265)

    #username
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class inkomen(models.Model):
        pg = models.ForeignKey(PersoonGegevens, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        inkomenfield = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

This is the form:

```
class inkomenForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta():
        model = inkomen
        fields = ('inkomenfield',)
```

This is my view:

```
def tijdelijk(request):
    #User id
    user = request.user.id

    if request.method == 'POST':
        incoming = inkomenForm(data=request.POST)

        if incoming.is_valid():
            incoming.save()
            return HttpResponse("saved")

        else:
            x = incoming.errors
            print (x)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/tijdelijk')
    else:
        incoming = inkomenForm()

    return render(request, 'index/tijdelijkeindex.html', {'inkomen':incoming})
```

I have tried:

```
incoming.save(commit=False)
incoming.pg = user
incoming.save
```

also readed the documentation about Inline formsets of django. But i dont really get

So i get the following error:(NOT NULL constraint failed) and i know it comes because i need to assign the pg.id and i know i can do that by adding the field in the form.py and let the user choose the id. But what i actually want is that pg = the logged in user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the return value of `form.save(commit=False)` to a variable, the return value is the created (but not committed to the database) model object

```
obj = incoming.save(commit=False)
obj.pg = user
obj.save()
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer it worked. Maybe something handy to know for people that visit this question to save the fk i needed a instance of the pk wich the fk is reffering to so i added: pg_id = PersoonGegevens.objects.filter(id=user)[0] below user = request.user.id and saved it as the hero described: obj = incoming.save(commit=False)
            obj.pg = pg_id
            obj.save().